# Remove the main menu from the homepage

Tags: xml, menu, magento2.2

I'm trying to **remove the main menu** from the homepage, for this I used the following code in my **custom template**:

```
<referenceBlock name="store.menu" remove="true" />
```

But the menu is still there while other settings in the template work fine.

What else should I do to remove this main menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final answer is:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

I wasn't referring to the correct block and, for some reason, I had to add a reference to the container.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the main menu from your home page do the following thing

**Create your own theme at this location**

> magento_root\app\design\frontend\Themes_package\theme\

**Create a theme folder there at below location**

> magento_root\app\design\frontend\Themes_package\theme\Magento_Theme

**Create a `default.xml` file there at below location**

> magento_root\app\design\frontend\Themes_package\theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

**Put this code there**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will remove your navigation section

Thank You!

Comment: Thanks for your answer which helped me finding the correct block. However, I just needed to do it for the homepage, not for all pages.

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions of Magento2, the remove method is now:

`<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>`

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```